# Fastest PCA under certain constraints

Tags: python, pca, numpy

I'd like to run PCA on some data, and it looks like there are a lot of ways to do it. What is the best way, given this information?

- The data is high-dimensional. Min: several thousand, max: around 150 million. Big range! Typically less than 10 million, I would think.
- The lower number of samples I can do this with, the better, but it could be up to thousands.
- I want to reconstruct the data (specifically only the most recent row), but with differing amounts of each principal component. For right now I plan on only modifying the first component, but it could be more later on.
- I may want to make the PCA computation again as time goes on.

What is the best choice? I've heard of [incremental PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_incremental_pca.html), or [thin SVD tracking](http://www.stat.osu.edu/~dmsl/thinSVDtracking.pdf), [data matrix SVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html), or [the covariance method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Computing_PCA_using_the_covariance_method). Even some rules of thumb would be useful.

Edit: I'm using Python + Numpy.

Comment: Will you be using OpenBlas, or a parallelized matrix library?

Comment: I wish I knew. Python is my constraint at this point.i guess your question is a part of my question.

Comment: Well, if you're using an Anaconda distribution (I don't), you should have access to Intel's MKL library (requires Intel processors) which parallelizes matrix computations. https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-distribution-for-python

Comment: Also, if memory requirements are above 20GB, I would recommend moving your work to AWS and using Spark. Spark allows general matrix computations; I'm not sure if they have a direct PCA function.